# Lightning Tab with Lightning Component throwing error (but the same component loads fine with App Preview, on SF1 & VF Page lightning out)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

We have a lightning component, which is being used in VF page Lightning out, SF1, App Preview & Lightning Tab in Lightning experience. Until Summer'16 it is working fine. Now it doesn't load in lightning experience, but loads fine in others.

The below is the error it throws when we are trying to load the lightning tab in lightning experience.

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 47a0514c-2363-44c2-8730-32e6f570915c)

[NoErrorObjectAvailable] An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 630801592-21079 (330301568)
    at AuraErrorInternal (https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2957:31)
    at new AuraError (https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2976:21)
    at AuraInstance.$reportError$ (https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14593:144)
    at https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:16427:8
    at Logger.$notify$ (https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2725:16)
    at Logger.log (https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2717:10)
    at Logger.error (https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2693:8)
    at AuraInstance.error (https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14551:17)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:1433:19), <anonymous>:15:8)
    at AuraComponentService.<anonymous> (https://my-domain.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:10489:7)
```

Thanks.

Update: My Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
Name
</aura:component>
```

Latest (15-June): The new component which was working until few mins ago is not loading now with the below error:

[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Access Check Failed! AuraComponentService.createComponentFromConfig(): 'markup://ltng:require' is not visible to 'markup://ilms:ImpactLMSCmp {158:1;0}'.
    at AuraErrorInternal (https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2957:31)
    at new AuraError (https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2976:21)
    at AuraInstance.$reportError$ (https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14593:144)
    at https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:16427:8
    at Logger.$notify$ (https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2725:16)
    at Logger.log (https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2717:10)
    at Logger.error (https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2693:8)
    at AuraInstance.error (https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14551:17)
    at AuraComponentService.$createComponentPriv$ (https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:10857:12)
    at componentConstructor.Component.$createComponentStack$ (https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:5071:49)

Awaiting your response.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying error from our logs shows a reference to a non-existent component and is of the form:

> aura://ComponentController/ACTION$getComponent error:
>   aura://ComponentController:
>   org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.DefinitionNotFoundException: No
>   COMPONENT named markup://namespace:name found

I am trying to identify the specific component now.

Comment: I created another component copy-pasted the same code (cmp,css & ctrl) and it works fine now.

Comment: Please see my post for the component code, clearly I dont think we are referencing any components there.

Comment: My Observation: The same code isn't working in the old component which exists before the LockerService (& others) update - but when I created a new component and copy-paste the same code - it works fine.

Btw, where does it say "DefinitionNotFoundException: No COMPONENT named " .. thanks for the help.

Comment: No COMPONENT named markup://ilms:ilms_ImpactLMSLearner found is the specific error message - I retrieved this from the server side logs - you should be able to find it in the browser's Network tab (not easy to find I know). Locker Service would have no impact on this - its not involved in access checks etc.

Comment: any update.
Is this related to this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127214/lighting-component-not-loading-in-safari-but-works-fine-in-chrome-firefox in any way.