# Lightning Component not loading in Safari, but works fine in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When I'm trying to load a component^ on Safari, I'm running into the below issue. But once I 'OK' these two dialogs everything else loads/works fine.

^ - which is working fine in Chrome & Firefox

Error1:

```
[NoErrorObjectAvailable] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'fn.apply')
throws at https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14073:18
AuraErrorInternal@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2957:40
AuraError@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2976:26
$reportError$@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14593:162
newHandler@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:16438:23
https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:16445:30
```

Error2:

```
[NoErrorObjectAvailable] SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement.
throws at https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6YXVyYUNvbnRhaW5lciIsImF0dHJpYnV0ZXMiOnsidmFsdWVzIjp7InRhZyI6ImlsbXM6SW1wYWN0TE1TQ21wIn19LCJ0IjoxNDY1OTc0Mzg2OTI4fQ==:5:32
AuraErrorInternal@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2957:40
AuraError@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:2976:26
$reportError$@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14593:162
newHandler@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:16438:23
https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:16445:30
appendChild@[native code]
evalAndReturn@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14056:32
value@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14072:31
create@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14184:66
onreadystatechange@https://impact-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:13765:34
```

I get the below error on Firefox at the bottom of the component, though everything works fine.

```
TypeError: fn is undefined throws at https://impact-dev-ed--ilms.na16.visual.force.com/auraFW/javascript/XyhLNaMJXc3t5qwu_xzuTA/aura_proddebug.js:14073:9
```

I'm not sure where/what to look, could you please give me some pointers/suggestions.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, removing jquery(completely) has fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

I am experiencing the same thing. My code worked about 3 weeks ago without this error. I didn't change anything, except to apply a bunch of Salesforce updates to my dev environment.

I have found it has something to do with the order of the loading of static Javascript via .

If I remove all external javascript, the error goes away.

When I upgraded jQuery 2.2.2 to 2.2.4, the error went away.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using only jquery, and it is pointing to 2.2.4

Comment: One other thing I've discovered is that the new [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html) is causing all kinds of issues.

Comment: The same, when I disabled Locker Service.

Comment: Surya Chandra Rao Gandreddi what critical update are you disabling in Setup? There is a plain Locker Service one and another that is specific to LS for Communities and the Communities one will have not impact outside of a community.

Comment: vNate we are working incredibly hard to resolve the issues that surface - many of the issues are not in LS itself but in the kind of exploits, uses of undocumented/unsupported APIs, reaching into the private DOM of components, etc and these are preexisting issues that have always been outlawed and put trust at risk but there was no way to enforce these API violations until now. Putting that genie back into the bottle is very challenging. For LS bugs we have been deploying fixes daily and have yet to push anything to the next release. Also API surface area we are covering is massive.

Comment: Thanks the reply Doug. We're not disabling anything I was just telling vNate.
We appreciate your hard work, thank you.